# Google Apps Script / How to set background color for a whole paragraph?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, http-status-code-403

I'm looking for a `.gs` function to change the background of an entire paragraph in Google Scripts through a Google Docs extension.

While I've been trying the code snippet from [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-set-a-background-color-for-an-entire-paragraph) which is using an external API call; and trying to get this to work, ideally it would be as simple as:

```
...
var paragraph = <some way of getting the paragraph>;
paragraph.setBackgroundColor('#112233');
...
```

#### Update 1 - UrlFetchApp is 403'ing for Google docs API

Highlighting the last line stopped working entirely - now I'm getting exceptions.

Upon trying the code from the published answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-set-a-background-color-for-an-entire-paragraph), I'm getting a `403 Unauthorized` from below:

```
  var baseUrl = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/";
  var headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()};
  // Logged the headers and it contains a bearer token, so it's not empty or null.
  var params = {headers: headers};
  // 403 from UrlFetchApp querying for docs.googleapis.com
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + id + "?fields=*", params);
```

This is what I have in the scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
```

And here's a snippet from the `appsscript.json`:

```
  "timeZone": "REDACTED",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Docs",
      "serviceId": "docs",
      "version": "v1"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

I've turned on the Docs API access through `Resources->Advanced Google Services` and it's looking like it's active through the menu:

[image]

#### Original Question

Looks like we have this answer available: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-set-a-background-color-for-an-entire-paragraph

but upon trying it out, it's only changing the background of the last line of a paragraph, instead of setting the whole, like the gif displays. It's also using an additional call; so I was wondering perhaps there's a newer API that'll set the paragraph background directly (not that the documents indicate that).

Comment: I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. When I tested this script, the background of the selected paragraph is changed. So I cannot replicate the situation of `but upon trying it out, it's only changing the background of the last line of a paragraph, instead of setting the whole, like the gif displays.`. I apologize for this. Can you provide the detail flow for replicating it?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you so much for coming back and following up on the answer. I've updated the question now, I'm getting a 403 from Docs API while it looks like I have the right scopes set up.

Comment: 1.There first scope needs to be `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` 2.What GCP are you using? Default or standard? Switch to standard GCP and enable the docs api.

Comment: Ah! Finally got it to work. I don't think it's anything to do with the default vs standard, but you were correct with the scope - it needs to be explicitly set in the manifest file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By the way, when the scopes are managed by the manifest file, the auto-detection of the scopes with the script editor cannot be used. So when the script is developing, this might not be suitable situation. In that case, when `// DocumentApp.create()` is put to the script editor as the comment line, the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` is automatically detected. By this, when you use other methods for using other scopes, the script editor can detect them.

Comment: Hi there @MaviDomates! To better document this situation, could you please share your working solution in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer published [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126354/how-can-i-set-a-background-color-for-an-entire-paragraph) to work.
I had to explicitly set the docs service in the `appsscript.json` - for some reason detecting it wasn't enough.

My `appsscript.json` looked like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "...",
  "dependencies": {
      "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
        "userSymbol": "Docs",
        "serviceId": "docs",
        "version": "v1"
      }]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Once that's done, the described solution worked for me.